# My auto suggestion is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ajax Auto Suggest</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}scripts/jquery-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function lookup(inputString) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("/search/", {q: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
 </script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #000;
    }
    h3 {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;   
    }
    .suggestionsBox {
        position: relative;
        left: 30px;
        margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #212427;
        -moz-border-radius: 7px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
        border: 2px solid #000; 
        color: #fff;
    }
    .suggestionList {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .suggestionList li {
        margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
        padding: 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .suggestionList li:hover {
        background-color: #659CD8;
    }
</style>
</head>
 <body>   
    <div>
        <form>
            <div>
                <br />
                <input type="text" size="30" value="" autocomplete="off" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
            </div>
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
                <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                    {% for value in result %}
                    <li onclick="fill({{ value }});">{{ value }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

I tried an example from `http://www.jeffadams.co.uk/2009/08/31/auto-suggest-with-php-jquery/` But it is not working for me. Where i am doing wrong? Can any one suggest?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but have you tried using the 'official' jquery autocomplete? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/